# Marianne Moore’s ‘Four Quartz Crystal Clocks’

Tags: poetry, interpretation, marianne-moore

Marianne Moore’s poem ‘[Four Quartz Crystal Clocks](http://bulletin.brynmawr.edu/articles/treasures-the-poet-and-the-gadget/)’ (1940) was first published in *The Kenyon Review* 2:3, pp. 284–285, and collected in [*What Are Years*](https://archive.org/details/whatareyears0000unse) (1941). Here's the first stanza (of seven):

> There are four vibrators, the world’s exactest clocks;
>       and these quartz time-pieces that tell
>   time intervals to other clocks,
>       these worksless clocks work well;
>   and all four, independently the
>       same are there, in the cool Bell
>           Laboratory time

(The version printed in [*Complete Poems of Marianne Moore*](https://archive.org/details/completepoemsofm0000moor) has slightly different wording in a couple of places: “independently the same, kept in / the 41° Bell” for lines 5–6, and “newborn progeny) that punctuality / is not a crime.” for lines 47–48.)

What is this poem about? What form is it written in? What is “the Giraudoux truth-bureau”? Is the third stanza a good explanation of a quartz clock’s sensitivity to temperature? What is the train of thought linking quartz clocks in the first stanza to Giradoux in the second to the lemur-student in the fourth to metathesis in the fifth? Why is the bell-boy carrying a buoy-ball? In what way does the speaking clock resemble the god Jupiter? Why does Jupiter tell Chronos that “punctuality is not now a crime”? What happened to the last line?

Comment: Some of this is explained in Marianne Moore's notes to her poem, which can be found in [The modern poets,: an American-British anthology](https://archive.org/stream/modernpoetsameribrin/modernpoetsameribrin_djvu.txt)

Comment: I assume *bell-boy* is some kind of wordplay on *bell-buoy*. See Kipling's poem [The Bell Buoy](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/46779/the-bell-buoy), which Marianne Moore probably knew. And I'm not at all sure the *bell-boy* has a *buoy ball*. Maybe the *buoy ball* is what is used to embarrass the *bell-boy*.

Comment: For the sixth stanza, there used to be numbers you could call which would say something like "At the tone, the time will be 3:46 pm and 15 seconds BEEEEP." In [New York City](https://medialoper.com/at-the-tone-the-time-lady-will-be-gone/), this number was  Meridian 7-1212 (637-1212).

Comment: From the OED: **embarrass,** 2b. *transitive.* To complicate or confuse (a matter, subject, issue, etc.); to render perplexing or problematic. Now somewhat rare.